# How to make excel automatically fill a value in a cell of a sheet when another corresponding cell of another sheet is filled the same value?

Tags: excel, vba

For example, I have cell A1 in sheet 1 and its value is "yes". If I fill in the cell A1 in sheet2 `='sheet1'!A1` then we know what is going on. However, how can I make the cell A2 in sheet2 also have "yes" when I fill in cell A2 of sheet1 without filling in cell A2 of sheet2 `='sheet1'!A2` ?

In other word, I want to make excel automatically fill a cell of sheet2 each time when I fill a value in corresponding cell of sheet1.

Comment: [Worksheet_Change Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the following event macro in the Sheet1 code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim r As Range
        For Each r In Target
            addy = r.Address
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range(addy).Value = r.Value
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: It helps!. Can you give a solution if I want to target to certain cell in sheet2. For example When I fill "yes" in A1 of sheet1, B5 of sheet2 will have "yes", and so for A2 of sheet1 and B6 of sheet2.

Comment: **YES** ........update your original post to reflect the mapping of Sheet1 cells to Sheet2 cells